# Error with if expression algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, compiler-errors

I want to pass in the values of `x`, `y` and `z`, and have them go through the algorithm. But I get an error. I think I'm doing something illegal, but I'm not sure.

The error is with this statement:

```
if((istrue1)||(istrue2&&istrue3)){
            ;
}
```

My full code is:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(int x, int y, int z) {
        boolean istrue1, istrue2, istrue3;

        if((istrue1=(x >=1 && x<=31)) || (istrue2=(y>=1 && y<=31)) || (istrue3=(z >= 1 && z<=31)));{
            if((istrue1)||(istrue2&&istrue3)){
                ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first problem I see is that there is a semicolon at the end of your outer if statement. The initialising istrue1 etc, inline in the if statement can make things hard to read, but also because the 'or' statement will short circuit istrue2 and isstrue3 won't be assigned to if itstrue1 is true.

Comment: You can't change the signature of `main`. Also, the first `true` will cause the initialization to terminate, because boolean-or short-circuits. Better to initialize your variables before your logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems in the code (but I suspect only the second is part of your issue here.

The first problem is that your outer if statement has a ';' at the end. So although it looks from the indenting that you have nested if statements, you don't really.

The second problem is a bit more subtle, and it's to do with the if statement short-circuiting the evaluation of its condition.

You have

```
if 
(
    a = first_condition ||
    b = second_condition ||
    c = third_condition
)
{
   ...do stuff
}
```

This is legal syntax, but if first_condition is true, then the compiler knows that the whole if condition is true, so it doesn't bother evaluating the second two clauses. That means, if first_condition is true, then neither 'b' nor 'c' will be assigned values.

My advice would be to redo the code as

```
boolean a = first_condition
boolean b = second_condition
boolean c = third_condition

if (a || b || c)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### There is so much wrong with your approach it is pretty much unsalvageable:

And to explain how and why all the problems in detail would be an entire class and is out of scope for StackOverflow because it would be too broad a subject.

That said, you did make an attempt so here is how to actually do part of what you are trying to do. Hopefully this will clarify how to work with `boolean` logic.

```
/* This removes the duplication of logic and remediates 
   the *line noise* looking code that duplication introduced.
*/
public static boolean inRangeInclusive(final int low, final int value, final int hi)
{
    return low <= value && value <= hi;
}

public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    final int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    final int z = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    if ( inRangeInclusive(1,x,31) || inRangeInclusive(1,y,31) || inRangeInclusive(1,z,31)) ;
    {
        /* whatever you want to happen if any of those things match goes here */
    }
}
```

1. Take the time to learn how to make all method args `final` and all `local` references `final` [it will save your more time than you can ever imagine](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/05/the-final-word-on-final/)!
2. If write something and it looks like `line noise` or the cat walked across the keyboard then it is probably wrong. Even if it appears to produce the behavior you desire.

Comment: I guess I have to initialize my bools, that solved the error I was getting.  However i still have logic error, (due to short-circuiting) so im gonna try your method. Thanks for the help.